# Black Screen Installing with AMD Graphics Card

Tags: graphics, laptop, ati

When I try to run Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop of a CD (also happens with wubi) I get a black screen. When I get the black screen I can't do anything except to force shutdown (by holding the power button). I have an AMD Radeon HD 6000G Series Card. My laptop: HP Pavilion G6

Answer (score 0):

For those that have AMD A-Series APUs, you need to get a minimal ISO for Oneiric (11.10) and then install complete system, or a Precise release newer than Alpha2 (12.04, although not recommended because it is still in development), this is because the fixes for your bug were on updates that appeared after the official release on Oneiric (11.10).